# Does Toad have a feature that allows you to jump directly to the line that contains the error?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

In SQLDeveloper, if I run the following code, the log window contains a list of errors. I can click on the error and it opens a new tab with about the right line number.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MySchema.MyPackage
AS
   PROCEDURE MyProcedure(
      param_in_ClassId               IN     NUMBER DEFAULT -1)
   IS
      Xmlfragment             VARCHAR2 (10000);
   BEGIN
        bad code
   END MyProcedure;

END MySchema;
/
```

In Toad, if I run the same code, it states:

> Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Does Toad have a feature that will list the compilation errors, and let me jump directly to them?

Toad lists the errors, but when I click on them, they search Google for the error code.

EDIT: Specifically, this script is a local file (.SQL, although I am extension ambivalent), so I would not be opening the package from the schema browser.

Comment: Open your package in schema browser, go to "errors" tab and double-click the line with your error.

Comment: I want to do this from an editor window. Is this possible?

Comment: Which version of Toad are you using? I tried your script with my old Toad (9.0.1.8) and the output was a list of errors (with only 1 row in this case); I clicked the error description in the error list and the procedure's row containing 'bad code' got highlighted in red. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, when opening the script from a file (the reason is that the script needs to be committed to TFS). I'm using version 12.1.0.22, which doesn't do that

Comment: Errors are shown after execution as Andre notes. If you execute with F9 then you get the Messages panel that is mentioned and you can click on them and jump. If you execute as script (F5) then you get text output just as you'd get from SQL*Plus. If you want to see those errors then your script needs to contain "SHOW ERRORS" at the end. You'll see errors in plain text, but you won't be able to jump to them. For script execution (> 1 statement) use F5. For compiling a single PL/SQL object or running a single SQL statement use F9.